# How to Memoize the solution to Unique Paths in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, memoization

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while. A M x N grid is given and we've to find number to paths from top left corner to bottom right corner.

Simple problem though; there are many solutions as well. Here're the details.
http://www.interviewbit.com/courses/programming/topics/math/problems/paths/
http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/11/unique-paths.html

I solved this problem in Java, and wrote one more solution in Python. Now I want to modify the previous solution with Memoized table so that the final answer gets collected at the bottom right cell. Value of a cell is the sum of its right and left adjacent cells.

[image: Value of a cell is sum of it's right and left cell]

Here's the code I can't debug:-

```
class Solution:
    #Actual Recursive function
    def paths(self,row,col):
        if row == 0 or col == 0:
            self.Mat[row][col] = 1
            return 1
        self.Mat[row][col-1] = self.paths(row, col-1)
        self.Mat[row-1][col] = self.paths(row-1, col)
        self.Mat[row][col] = self.Mat[row][col-1] + self.Mat[row-1][col]
        return self.Mat[row][col] 

    # Driver Function. This will be called
    def uniquePaths(self, A, B): 
        self.Mat = [[-1]*B]*A
        ans = self.paths(A-1, B-1)
        return self.Mat[A-1][B-1]
```

And here is my previous solution that works - But doesn't use memoized table.

```
class OldSolution:
    def paths(self,row,col):
        if row==0 or col==0:
            return 1
        elif row<0 or col<0:
            return 0
        elif row >0 and col > 0:
            return self.paths(row-1,col) + self.paths(row,col-1)            
    def uniquePaths(self, A, B):
        Mat = [ [-1] * B ] *A
        return self.paths(A-1, B-1)

sol = OldSolution()
print sol.uniquePaths(3,3) # Prints 6
```

Test Cases:-
3, 3 = 6

15, 9 = 319770

Comment: "Value of a cell is the sum of its right and left adjacent cells."  It looks like it's actually the sum of the _above_ and left cells.  (According to your leetcode.com link, paths can only ever move right or down.)

Comment: Your first link to interviewbit.com produces a login page --- whatever you intended to show us appears to be members-only.  I think the second outlines the problem well enough, but you might want to mention the "downward or rightward moves only" rule in your text, because the first thing I thought was along the lines of, "there's a a lot more paths than _that_".

Comment: An alternative approach:  Python's tuples are hashable, so they can be used as dictionary keys.  Your memoization cache could be a single `dict` mapping a `(row, col)` tuple to an `int`.  Or, if you feel it's not cheating (and you're using Python 3.2 or greater), use the [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the initialization of the matrix. You essentially create the same row duplicated in every column so when you update a cell, all corresponding cells in all columns get updated.

Instead of:

```
self.Mat = [[-1]*B]*A
```

Use:

```
self.Mat = [[-1 for i in range(B)] for j in range(A)]
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Rather [[-1 for i in range(B)] for j in range(A)] in this particular case..